# Running Grunt on a TFS2013 Build Agent

Tags: gruntjs, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I'm looking to use grunt to perform some minification and automatic script referencing on an Angular application just before it's deployed by TFS to the relevant server.

I have grunt scripts running successfully on my local machine via both post-build scripts or running a .bat file post build containing something along the lines of:

cd $(ProjectDir)
npm install
grunt

However, this does not appear to work on the TFS Build Agent and i get 9009 errors or similar indicating that the server does not recognise the commands i'm trying to run.

I have installed the same components on the TFS as i have on my local machine. And have tested that if i manually navigate to the project directory and run either the .bat or open up a command prompt and run the above commands. These both work, the problem appears to be related to how i'm referencing the grunt scripts from MSBuild, i suspect i'm not understanding the correct process here.

Has anyone managed to get this working before?

Comment: I managed to get round the npm install error by adding the following empty folder for the NetworkService user: C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution but i got round this by:

Adding the empty npm folder for the Network Service user:
 C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm

Then, in my script. I referenced Grunt's full path:

C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt.cmd